# To remove spaces from df.to_markdown()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

By reading text files into data frame, I want to add a new column based on the values in the existing columns, i.e. adding the numeric values from 'Stock' and 'Delivery'.

The problem is, the original data (from data supplier), was generated from "df.to_markdowns()".

Seems I can't remove the white spaces.

```
ds = pd.read_csv("C:\\TEMP\\ff.txt", sep="|", header = 0, skipinitialspace=True)
ds.columns = ds.columns.str.strip()

df['new'] = ds['Stock'] + ds['Delivery']

print (df)
```

[image]

What would be the way to handle such case?

By the way, this simulates the text file creation from "df.to_markdown()"

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Price': [59,98,79],
'Stock': [53,60,60],
'Delivery': [11,7,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with open("C:\\TEMP\\ff.txt", 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(df.to_markdown() + "\n")

outfile.close
```

Comment: Please provide a copyable example so I can test if my solution works.

Comment: Is the goal to just remove the white spaces between the "stock" and "delivery" values, or to actually add these numeric values?

Comment: @Kurt Kline, to add these numeric values.

Comment: @MarkK what version pandas are you using?

Comment: @KurtKline, I am using Pandas 1.0.5.

Comment: @user2640045, please find the txt file here: https://tmpfiles.org/download/91538/ff.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
ds = pd.read_csv(
    "C:\\TEMP\\ff.txt",
    sep="|",
    skiprows=[1],
    skipinitialspace=True
)
ds.columns = ds.columns.str.strip()
ds = ds.loc[:, ["Price", "Stock", "Delivery"]]
ds['new'] = ds['Stock'] + ds['Delivery']

print(ds)
```

output

```
   Price  Stock  Delivery  new
0     59     53        11   64
1     98     60         7   67
2     79     60         6   66
```

`skiprows=[1]` skips the row at index 1, which is the row with the `--------:`

With this row removed from the dataframe, pandas automatically interprets the `Price`, `Stock`, and `Delivery` columns as integers, which allows the statement `ds['new'] = ds['Stock'] + ds['Delivery']` to work as expected.

Comment: brilliant! thank you for your help, and sharing knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

This works on the example you have provided:

`pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/ff.txt", sep=r"\s*\|\s*", engine="python", skiprows=[1])[["Price", "Stock", "Delivery"]]`

If you want something else I suggest you provide an example for it.

Comment: ...question desired solution is a lacking details then! OP to repair. EoR.

Comment: User... add some context to stay away from bots marking solution as "low quality".

Comment: @user2640045, you're right! your solution works! but can I have your understanding that I chose another answer which provides more details?

Comment: @MarkK haha that’s totally alright. I thought you wanted me to guess what else you want. In that case I wanted you to change your example to the explain better what exactly you want.